# Xamarin Forms Shell - Navigation to old navigation stack rather than flyout page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m having trouble with my Xamarin Forms Shell app. I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behaviour, can someone point me in the right direction.

I have an app with 2 pages in the Visual Shell Hierarchy:

Search & History

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Search" Icon="search.png">
    <Tab Title="Search">
        <ShellContent Route="searchpage">
            <views:SearchPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="History" Icon="history.png">
    <Tab Title="History">
        <ShellContent>
            <views:HistoryPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And several pages (let’s call them PageA, PageB and PageC) registered like so:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("PageA", typeof(PageA));    
Routing.RegisterRoute("PageB", typeof(PageB));    
Routing.RegisterRoute("PageC", typeof(PageC)); (Oops, I should probably use nameof here)
```

Anyway, I start on the Search page and navigate to PageA like so:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PageA");
```

Because PageA is not in the visual hierarchy, this gives me a navigation stack like so:

```
"//searchpage/PageA"
```

Using the same relative navigation approach, I navigate to PageB then PageC, so my navigation stack is like so:

```
"//searchpage/PageA/PageB/PageC"
```

From PageC, I use the flyout menu to navigate to History, the history page opens fine.

Now on the history page, I use the flyout menu again and click the Search tab

But I'm not taken to the search page as expected, I'm taken back to PageC (taken back to my previous navigation stack).

From this page (PageC) if I use the flyout menu again and click the Search tab, it navigates correctly to the Search page.

How should this work and how can I stop it navigating to PageC when I select the Search tab from the flyout?

Thanks

(ps - I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.7 at present)

Comment: Same behaviour with the [official sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/)

Comment: Hi, it seems to be a normal phenomenon. When switching flyout item, it will not change the stack order of each item. It needs user to operate it manually. But the second times, maybe the shell will clear the stack.

Comment: In addition, if using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync`, the next page will not show the `FlyoutIcon` menu. Therefore, from PageC, you could share the code of how to use the flyout menu to navigate to History.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right... The PageA, PageB and PageC is a goods ordering process, so when the user gets to PageC (the OrderSuccess page), I do not want the user to press the back button, back to the Payment page. So I have hidden the top bar... Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ... and in the place of the back button, I have added a menu button which shows the flyout ... Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true ... I did this some time ago, so forgot this was different from the norm.  I'm going to try and make PageC a ShellItem in the Shell XAML and navigate to that route page, see if this solves it.

Comment: I was hoping a call to a route page would reset the stack... but moving PageC to a route ShellItem in the Shell XAML and calling it, does not solve the problem... The full stack is still presented when navigating to SearchPage (but now it is PageB).  The only way I can think of sorting this, is to make every page a route page (using a ShellItem) and creating the navigation myself between the pages and then the SearchPage will never have a stack, so the flyout will work as expected... This is fine... but I can't be the first person affected by this... surely there is a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Craig Okey, got it. Your needs actually is a good feature request. However, you know making the flayout shows in `PageC`, it alredy brokes the current design of Shell navigation. The designer want user to click back button then can back to root page. The best idea to achieve your needs is to override the click event of flayout items. Then can using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../../")` to reset the stack bofore navigating to the destination flayout item page.

Comment: @Craig However, I could not find a way to override the click event of flayout item. Maybe you could submit a feature request in Github [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose). Then there will be engineers from Microsoft to know the needs. If they accept this feature request, they will update this in the next version of xamrin forms. If you have submitted it, remember to share the link here. I also will follow it up there.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yeah sure, I'll submit a feature request for this and I'll share the link when it is done. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be raising this as a feature request when I get 5 minutes, but I have found a solution to this issue.

1. I made the last page (PageC) a Root page and removed it from my Routes Script. I did this by adding the following to the AppShell.Xaml like so:

   ```
   <ShellItem Route="PageC">
       <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PageC}" />
   </ShellItem>

   and removing this code:
   Routing.RegisterRoute("PageC", typeof(PageC));
   ```
2. Now when navigating to PageC, I am no longer pushing onto the stack with a relative navigation, I am now navigating to a root page like so:

   ```
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//PageC");
   ```
3. Before we navigate to PageC, we need to clear the current navigation stack.  I tried PopToRootAsync, but this showed the SearchPage before navigating to PageC. I found the following code works:

   ```
        // FYI - Navigation Stack: //SearchPage/PageA/PageB

        var pageB = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack[2];
        var pageA = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack[1];

        Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(pageB);
        Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(pageA);

        // Now navigate to our route page, PageC.
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//PageC");
   ```

I will be using a slightly more elegant way of getting the pages rather than hard coding the index, but thought this was the easiest way to demonstrate what was happening.

The next time I navigate to the SearchPage now, I get the SearchPage

Comment: Glad found the solution! Not forget to mark this as answer when you have time. Then others who have the same needs will know that.

Comment: @Craig Is this right, if to clear stack, have to add page in Shell visual hierarchy?

Comment: @ThamaraiT No, to clear stack you have to navigate to the root.  Adding a page in the visual hierarchy just enables that page to be a root page.

Comment: Need to submit a feature request, because official document says the page is always at root when a page is defined in Shell visual hierarchy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#perform-navigation

Comment: @ThamaraiT This is the case already. Only when you add a page (page 2 on to page 1... adding a page that is not in the visual hierarchy)... page 2 stays in place when you navigate away and back to page 1 when using the menu.

Comment: This case force us to add Page C in Shell visual hierarchy even your app didn't need the Page C in flyout, right?

Comment: @Craig Meanwhile I too stuck at the same situation and planning to quit using Shell feature. Can you check my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085818/how-to-define-different-items-in-flyout-menu-and-bottom-tabbar-in-xamarin-forms/65086574#comment115098082_65086574

Comment: Luckily I have managed to 'bolt on' the pages I needed outside the visual hierarchy (VH) to pages in the VH. I also made sure that I removed the burger menu from these pages and when I navigate to another page (via my own button) I made sure that I pop'd the page from the stack before navigating on... so the next time the user will see the initial VH page.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Just check this, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/159748/app-shell-pop-to-root-on-tab-tap . As per this, it seems to work fine in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for answers, an answer by [Damir's Corner](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20210326-UnreliableNavigationToRootPage.html)

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{tag}", false); //Checks the Navigation Stack Downward
```

The code above checks the current Navigation Stack, and searches for the Route Tag Downward (or inside the Navigation Stack) and then replaces the entire Stack with the Found Route.

Hope this helps for those looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

When jumping between different tabs (and by doing so different navigationstacks), Williams solution (Damir's Corner) worked for me.

My scenario:

- Tab1 -> ListPage -> DetailsPage
- Tab2 -> CreateStep1Page -> CreateStep2Page

After saving the entry in CreateSpecificPage, I navigate two times:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(CreateStep1Page)}", false);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(ListPage)}/{nameof(DetailsPage)}", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is intentional. One thing to understand is that as mentioned in the docs, every Tab contains separate navigation stack, Shell.Current.Navigation points to the currently active/visible Tab navigation stack. So what you can do is actually quite simple.

You just override Shell.OnNavigating event, and from remove every page except root one from the current navigation stack only if you are navigating between different route trees.

Like, from //route1/page1 to //route2/page2.

You can adapt following code per your use case.

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Setup.RegisterRoutes(this);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if (args.Current != null && args.Target != null && args.Current.Location.OriginalString.StartsWith("//") && args.Target.Location.OriginalString.StartsWith("//")) {
            var currentRoot = args.Current.Location.OriginalString.TrimStart('/').Split('/').First();
            var targetRoot = args.Target.Location.OriginalString.TrimStart('/').Split('/').First();
            
            // we are navigating between tabs
            if (!string.Equals(currentRoot, targetRoot, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1) {
                for (var i = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```