# How to define different items in Flyout menu and bottom tabbar in Xamarin Forms 4.8 version using Shell?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am developing an application in Xamarin Forms 4.8 version with both side menu(Flyout) and bottom `Tabbar` using Shell feature. My sidemenu has 4 items and the bottom `Tabbar` has 5 items. Both are having different items. The bottom `Tabbar` with such 5 items are always needs to be present around my application. When I click on any item inside the menu, the bottom `Tabbar` items are replaced with side menu items. I don't know why.

My AppShell.xaml page is shown below,

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
        xmlns:localHome="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.Home"
        xmlns:localOnlineStore="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.OnlineStores"
        xmlns:localBooks="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.BookList"
        xmlns:localUniforms="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.Uniforms"
        xmlns:localUser="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.User"
        xmlns:localMyAccount="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.MyAccount"
        xmlns:localCart="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.Cart"
        xmlns:flyouthead="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Renderer;assembly=MyApp"
        Title="MyApp"
        x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"   
        FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
        FlyoutHeaderBehavior="Fixed"
        FlyoutBackgroundColor="#011948">           
    
        <Shell.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#011948</Color>
                ...
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary>
         </Shell.Resources>    
    
         <Shell.FlyoutHeader> ... </Shell.FlyoutHeader> 
         <Shell.ItemTemplate> ... </Shell.ItemTemplate>
         <Shell.MenuItemTemplate> ... </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
    
    
        <TabBar>
           <Tab Title="Home"
                Icon="ic_home">
                <ShellContent Route="HomePage" Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localHome:HomePage}" />
           </Tab>
           <Tab Title="Books"
                Icon="ic_book">
                <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Cart"
                Icon="ic_cart">
                <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Uniforms"
                Icon="ic_uniform">
                <ShellContent Route="UniformsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localUniforms:UniformsPage}" />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Profile"
                Icon="ic_profile">
                <ShellContent Route="MyProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localMyAccount:MyProfilePage}" />
             </Tab>
      </TabBar>    
    
    
      <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">         
          <ShellContent Title="Online Store" Icon="ic_online_store" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localOnlineStore:OnlineStorePage}" />
          <ShellContent Title="About Us" Icon="ic_about_us" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localHome:AboutUsPage}" />
          <ShellContent Title="Contact Us" Icon="ic_contact_us" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localHome:ContactUsPage}" />
          <ShellContent Title="Sign In" Icon="ic_login" Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localUser:LoginPage}" />
       </FlyoutItem>    
    
 </Shell>
```

When I run in Android Emulator, my bottom tabbar looks like in the image below

[image: Bottom Tabbar]

and side menu in Flyout as below

[image: Side Menu in Flyout]

When I click on items inside the menu, the page is rendered as follows

[image: Side menu overrides bottom tabbar]

Here, the bottom `Tabbar` items are replaced with side menu items.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display one or more items in the flyout and bottom, you can use a FlyoutItem.

```
 <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

[image]

If you just want to display items in the bottom, don't want to display items in the flyout,  you just need to use TabBar to do this,

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent>
            <views:AboutPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent>
            <views:ItemsPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

[image]

Just choose FlayoutItem or TabBar, don't need to use both of them.

For more detailed info about Shell, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create

**Update:**

```
 <MenuItem
    Clicked="OnMenuItemClicked"
    StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle"
    Text="Logout" />


 private async void OnMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
    }
```

Comment: It seems, we can't use both Flyout and Tabbar in Shell, right?

Comment: But XF Shell allows to have both Flyout and Tabbar in application. Why can't be possible to have different items in both?

Comment: @ThamaraiT [Xamarin.Forms Shell Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#single-page-application) said that Shell object can only ever contain FlyoutItem objects or a TabBar object, which can only ever contain Tab objects, which can only ever contain ShellContent objects.The TabBar type disables the flyout.

Comment: Then, what is the way of having bottom tabbar in all my pages along with side menu using Shell feature?

Comment: @ThamaraiT I think that adding  FlyoutItem in shell can reach your goal. Please see my reply above.

Comment: @ThamaraiT If you just want to display side menu, bottom tabbar, navigate to different page, you can use **MenuItem**. Please see my update.

Comment: @ Cherry Bu - MSFT using menuitem, page is added to navigation stack. When I click on menu item(e.g. Contact Us) in side menu from Home page(bottom tabbar), respective page is added to stack. Now I click a page (e.g. Uniforms) in bottom tabbar, respective page is rendered without adding to stack. Because the page is in Shell Navigation Hierarchy. Now I click Home page in bottom, Contact Us page is shown. I don't know why.

Comment: According to Hierarchical Navigation in document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/lifecycle#hierarchical-navigation, stack need to be cleared. But in my case it is not.

Comment: @ThamaraiT So you have solved your problem? If yes, please mark the helpful reply, or share your solution, thanks.

Comment: Each tabbar object in my app, holds the last visited page in stack. It seems my app requirement didn't suit to use Xamarin.Shell feature. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Shell in Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2012 too have the same feature, by which we can have either flyout or tabbar **not both** as root menu for our application. We can define menu items in Flyout when our application is based on tabbar root menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your tabs depending on what you put in your `AppShell.xaml`, while for the flyout you can overwrite it by setting your custom content/view (flyout items won't follow your `AppShell.xaml`), either by setting the bindable property [Shell.FlyoutContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#replace-flyout-content) with a direct content or [Shell.FlyoutContentTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#replace-flyout-content) with a `DataTemplate` instead. This way you will have different items between your tabs and flyout.

```
<Shell X:Name="shell" ..>
...
<Shell.FlyoutContent>
    <CollectionView BindingContext="{x:Reference shell}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                       TextColor="White"
                       FontSize="Large" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Shell.FlyoutContent>
```

#### Note

This property is available starting from Xamarin.Forms **5.0.0.2012**

#### Related question

[Dynamically create list of FlyoutItem in Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65911023)

Comment: It could be an answer but there is not a real example on the MS page and the code crashes with this error:  Cannot find the object referenced by `shell`

Comment: Are you sure you are inside Shell element using the xamarin forms version mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Forms => 5.0.0.2012. I have even reported bugs in the GitHub repo about other controls. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SaveThatPower.Views"
       x:Name="SP_AppShell"
       Title="Save That Power"
       FlyoutIcon="menu.png"`

Comment: Since you have `x:Name="SP_AppShell"` I think it might be coming from there, I am using `BindingContext="{x:Reference shell}"` so you should change `shell` with `SP_AppShel` or you already did it? The reference used in binding and X:Name must match

Comment: Yes, I changed it, and still didn't trigger the Flyout.

Comment: I shared my question and code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/442671/how-to-use-a-tabbar-and-a-flyout-both-in-the-xamar.html

Comment: I mean did the error you mentioned before disappeared with that change ? Is there that error or the behaviour expected in this question is not working.

Comment: I didn't get an error but nothing happened. It didn't trigger the menu.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete I noticed that `IsGrouped` property was causing the issue in the context where the bound collection is not correctly setup for grouping, you might need to remove it, i have updated my answer. please let me know if that was helpful.

Comment: Hi, nothing has changed. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete unfortunately i cannot reproduce, it is working for me.

Comment: Can you share your code in a GitHub repo? It will be useful to do a comparison.