# How to show different items in Flyout item and different items in bottom tab bar using Xamarin forms shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on hamburger menu and bottom tab bar items. Below is my AppShell.xaml file.

```
<!-- LoginPage -->
<ShellContent Route="login"
     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}">
</ShellContent>

<FlyoutItem Route="about" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Currently same items are displaying in both Flyout menu and bottom tabs. But as per my requirement in Flyout menu I have to show AboutPage and Browse page and in bottom tabs I have to show Market Tab and Address tab. But it is showing only About tab and Browse tab in bottom tabs. Can anyone tell how to show different items in bottom tabs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define different items in Flyout menu and bottom tabbar in Xamarin Forms 4.8 version using Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085818/how-to-define-different-items-in-flyout-menu-and-bottom-tabbar-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `MenuItem` to show the items in the Flyout. And use the `FlyoutItem` to show the tabs in the bottom tabbar without setting the `FlyoutDisplayOptions` property to `AsMultipleItems`.

Xaml:

```
<MenuItem
    Command="{Binding AboutCommand}"
    Icon="tab_about.png"
    Text="About" />

<FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Title="Market" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Market}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Address" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Address}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Code behind:

```
  public ICommand AboutCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigatedToAbout());         

    async Task NavigatedToAbout()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("about");
    }
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("about", typeof(AboutPage));
   
        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: preview]

Comment: Hi Wendy, thanks for the idea but how do you remove the extra item in gray at the bottom of the app?